# Getting individual elements from a Visio master group file using C#

Tags: visio

I need to create a Visio document and add shapes from a .vss file. I am able to add simple shapes and add text to it without any issues. But I am having issues when I am trying to add a shape which is a collection of 4 rectangles grouped together (I believe it's called a master) and add texts to each shape.

I want to populate values (add texts) in each of these rectangle shapes in the group. Once I drop this master into the Visio page, it's appearing as a group. I am able to ungroup each rectangle with the `Ungroup()` method. But I don't know how to get each individual element from this group. Is there a way I can uniquely identify each element in this group? Or iterate through the group and find each element? Please see the code below, what I did so far.

```
Visio.Document doc = application.Documents.Add(@"\example.vst");
Visio.Page page = application.Documents[1].Pages[1];
Visio.Documents vdocs = application.Documents;
Visio.Document visioStencil = vdocs.OpenEx(@"\sample.vss", (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);
Visio.Page visioPage = application.ActivePage;
Visio.Shapes visShapes = visioPage.Shapes;
//the following shape in the setensil is the group of 4 rectanle I was referring 
Visio.Master visioConvMaster = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Conveyance");
Visio.Shape visioConvShape = visioPage.Drop(visioConvMaster, 4.25, 5.5);
//try to ungroup to get each 
visioConvShape.Ungroup();
```

Any idea how I should proceed further? I am really new to Microsoft technologies. I am using Visual Studio 2012 professional & Visio 2010 Premium.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Visio.Shape objects have a property "Shapes", which is a collection of child shapes. Don't ungroup; first, iterate through the Shapes collection (visioConvShape.Shapes[0], visioConvShape.Shapes[1], etc.) and then if you need to ungroup, do so after you have either at least performed whatever action you need to or identified them and/or given them reusable names.